# windows xp client not working with clearcase 8 server

Tags: registry, upgrade, clearcase

As part of upgrade to clearcase 8 from clearcase 7.0, I have created a new registry server and copied the vob into the new server. Now, I have installed clearcase client 7.1.2 on windows 7 machine and it works fine. The same client on windows xp pointing to the new registry server with clearcase 8 is not working. It says

Problem:

An error occurred trying to access the ClearCase registry server xxx

Recommendation:

There may be networking problems.  If access to other computers via TCP/IP is 
working, then xxx may be down or may need to be rebooted.

Could you please give an idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

The main document to consult in this instance is the "[Compatibility across releases for ClearCase clients and servers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21597061)", which does mention that CC 7.1.2 client is compatible with a CC8.x server.

But depending on the FL (Feature Level), you might have to switch to a CC8 client (FL7 and more).

A ClearCase client 7.1.x does support Windows Xp (as mentioned in the "[System Requirements for ClearCase 7.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974#windows)"), but only SP2 or SP3.

---

The OP confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113558/windows-xp-client-not-working-with-clearcase-8-server/29115895#comment46659296_29115895):

> Its all working now.
>   But the same error still is reported by ccdoctor: looks like a false error as everything is working fine all clearcase operations.
>   Strange.

Comment: I am able to use clearcase 7.1 client fine on the same xp machine with clearcase 7.0 server. but, i am getting this error with clearcase 8.0 server (feature level is 5)

Comment: @user2636464 and cleartool ccdoctor doesn't say anything more than a possible network error?

Comment: can this be a firewall related issue?

Comment: @user2636464 yes: anything that can influence the connection can be a culprit. Also, are all the ClearCase services started on your Xp CC client?

Comment: is there anything that can be done to troubleshoot this ? I am clueless.

Comment: @user2636464 mainly contact IBM support, to check with them if there is some kind of incompatibility between a CC 7.1.2 client and a CC8 registry server.

Comment: well its all working now . but  the same error still is reported by ccdoctor. looks like a false error as everything is working fine all clearcase operations.strange

Comment: @user2636464 Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

The registry server can be different from the vob server and the view server and eventually your own station.

if the registry server is not accessible through network .. the clearcase doctor analysis say :

> **Problem:** Regions "windows" and/or "unix" unknown on registry server "cmserv".
>
> **Solution:** You must be within a network region to refer to VOB or view storage directories.

If it is not the case, and pinging the server reaches it correctly, verify that your credentials are coherent between your station and the registry server. The albd server service is working with enough privileged rights. Ports are authorized by the firewall.

using the albd server account: 
`<ClearCase_Home>/etc/utils/credmap your_registry_server`

You can make a simple test accessing the registry server by listing vobs, regions, views

```
cleartool lsreg
```

For ClearCase regions.

**Ideas:** regarding your station under Windows seven: ensure you are connecting the right registry server (the one under CC8).
Execute a `<clearcase_home>/etc/utils/creds` and compare with what you have on the XP station and with what you have in the server.

Installing Wireshark, ok it is a little bit tricky at this point but, I already found network issues with analysing the communication behaviours between the station and the server.

**Complements:** when you said it works on W7 7.1.2 to CC8 registry server, it means you are able to start a dyamic view on a VOB and the checkout command is working fine in your context. (I suppose here your registry server is also your VOB server and your view server is your station.)

Comment: Hi, clearcase doctor reports what I have suggested in my question.I suspect it to be a firewall issue.But, I am not very confident on finding if it really is firewall issue. otherwise, I have to contact ibm support as the last resort.

Comment: If you have tcpview (from MS Sysinternals, or ProcessHacker 2.33) you can see all ports opened by albd server, VOB server or your station.